# Windows Server 2012 Read-only checkbox on folder

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2

I have WordPress installed on Windows Server 2012 R2 / IIS 7.5.

I have a custom theme installed via the Dashboard in WordPress and it is a *fancy* one where there is a section to play with theme settings and add custom CSS.

I have an issue with the Custom CSS bit. My custom CSS doesn't actually show up. So I thought it might be a permissions issues.

I check the permissions and `wp-content` has `IIS_USRS` with all permissions granted, **but** it also had the read only box checked (or a little black square in there) which I un-checked.

[image: readonly checkbox]

What does that checkbox do? I've already told the server that `IIS_USRS` can do read/write to that folder. But if that checkbox is checked, which would the server listen to?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can ignore the state of that checkbox - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/326549/you-cannot-view-or-change-the-read-only-or-the-system-attributes-of-folders-in-windows-server-2003,-in-windows-xp,-in-windows-vista-or-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file that is set to read-only cannot be altered. Setting the checkbox on a folder is just a quicker way to apply it to all files in the folder.

The read-only attribute on a file can be unset by anyone with "Write" permissions. It is regarded as a safety-net against inadvertent file changes.

But as long as it is set, the file cannot be altered by anyone including `IIS_USRS`.